# RestTemplate 400 error for get request spring 6 apache httpclient5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, apache-httpclient-5.x

When i use new instance of resttemplate like,
''' RestTemplate r = new RestTemplate();'''

And hit my service,i get success.
But the moment i add,

'''Resttemplate r = new Resttemplate();
r.setRequestfactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());'''
I start getting 400 bad request in **get calls** while **post calls still working**.
I am using spring 6 and jdk 17 and apache httpclient5.
Previously with spring 5.x and apache client 4,it was working fine.

Comment: Solution seems simple - if it works without, just don't use `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`

Comment: @Jorn i have given just for reference new  object of HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory, in real scenerio we are using connection pooling and timeouts with HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.So we cant really remove this requestfactory

Comment: How come 2 requestfactories making difference in rest api get calls.default is simplerequestfactory where as ours is HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory

Comment: Well, they clearly produce different requests. You'll need to figure out what about the request is different.

Comment: @jorn The request is a simple http get request accessible by browser and postman too.Its just a url which dont expect any headers or parameters.what should i compare in requestfactories?Also same call and same code works fine prior to upgrade to spring6 and springboot3.x